# Ajax POST with csrfmiddlewaretoken and csrftoken cookie set still gets django 403 Forbidden

Tags: ajax, django-csrf, csrf-protection

I've read that both the csrfmiddlewaretoken and the csrftoken cookie have to be the correct value for a django POST request to succeed ([django: csrftoken COOKIE vs. csrfmiddlewaretoken HTML Form value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588374/django-csrftoken-cookie-vs-csrfmiddlewaretoken-html-form-value)). This is the case for me yet I still get a 403:

In the chrome console:

```
document.cookie
```

returns

```
"csrftoken=Wt9eeJop5Vb3OmeNTvogegckm1pVM5MD"
```

but

```
$.get('https://learningdollars.fwd.wf/csrftoken/', function(data){
    console.log(data)
    token = $.parseHTML(data)[0].value
    console.log(token)
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'https://learningdollars.fwd.wf/confirmemail/',
        data: {email: 'gdasu@alumni.stanford.edu', csrfmiddlewaretoken: token},
        contentType: "application/json"
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        console.log('done!')
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
        console.log('fail!')
    })
})
```

returns

```
> Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
> <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='Wt9eeJop5Vb3OmeNTvogegckm1pVM5MD' />
> Wt9eeJop5Vb3OmeNTvogegckm1pVM5MD
> POST https://learningdollars.fwd.wf/confirmemail/ 403 (Forbidden)
> fail!
```

I have

```
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
```

activated in my django middleware.

My root urls.py contains:

```
url(r'^csrftoken/$', views.get_csrf_token),
url(r'^confirmemail/$', views.confirm_email, name='confirm_email'),
```

And, my views are:

```
def get_csrf_token(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    print c
    return render_to_response('csrf.html', c)

def confirm_email(request):
    print 'here'
    return JsonResponse({'response': 0})
```

And by the way, the contents of csrf.html are just the csrftoken (inside an input tag):

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I found a solution. It was just sending in the data as a URI rather than as json. (I by the way tried specifying dataType: 'json' in the above to no avail.) The following is in the chrome console:

```
> email = 'gdasu@alumni.stanford.edu'
< "gdasu@alumni.stanford.edu"

> csrftoken = 'L2MxD1XQIF1Xto5NkzUgGUYiHPyyz3K5'
< "L2MxD1XQIF1Xto5NkzUgGUYiHPyyz3K5"

> $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'https://learningdollars.fwd.wf/confirmemail/',
    data: "email="+ encodeURI(email) + "&csrfmiddlewaretoken=" + encodeURI(csrftoken),
    success: function(data) { console.log(data); }
})

< Object {response: 1}
```

Still unsure what I was doing wrong on the json side, but the following is what I tried:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://learningdollars.fwd.wf/confirmemail/",
    data: JSON.stringify({ email: email, csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    },
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can forbid Django CSRF by adding csrf_exempt to tell the view not check csrf token.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def get_csrf_token(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    print c
    return render_to_response('csrf.html', c)

@csrf_exempt
def confirm_email(request):
    print 'here'
    return JsonResponse({'response': 0})
```

Comment: The CSRF token should be used if you're using unsafe methods such as POST to help defend against cross site request forgery.