# Microsoft Edge Browser Django Admin login not working

Tags: django, django-admin, microsoft-edge, django-2.0

I am trying to login on django admin using Microsoft Edge Browser, but there is no luck that I can login to the admin site. Everything is working in other browsers even on internet explorer it's working smoothly except some CSS issues. I have tried everything from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52252990/django-admin-returns-403-forbidden-error-on-microsoft-edge-after-consecutive-pos) link from comments, still no luck.   Any help?

Comment: Do you have any error output from either your server logs and/or Edge's console (Network)? Which Django version is this. What exatly is "no luck" - is there an error or is the page simply reloaded without an error? Is this the vanilla Admin or have you loaded additional modules like django-allauth or django-suit or some CMS etc. that might hook into the login process?

Comment: @Risadinha There is no error  on console, when I submits the form it just reloads the page back to the login page. And In every browser Site is working smoothly. Django version 2.0, and yes django-suit is there.

Comment: Can you try without django suit? (Django Suit officially only supports up to Django 1.10)

Comment: Thanks @Risadinha , it worked for django admin login but not worked for custom admin login, and it's same case as was with Other browsers, Only edge it's not working but with other browsers it working, surprisingly it works on mobile edge browser. Only Desktop edge browser behaving weird. I have removed django-suit from project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django Suit officially only supports up to Django 1.10.

As confirmed by the OP, removing Django Suit from the project resolved the issue.